# Templated enum operator overload resolution

Tags: c++, templates, enums, operator-overloading

I'm trying to put some typesafe flags into several related classes (more than just the two I use as examples here), which I am currently doing with an `enum TypeFlags` in each class. I'd like to define an operator| on each of these enums. I can do this by writing separate `operator|` function for each of `KeyEvent::TypeFlags`, `MouseEvent::TypeFlags`, etc., or, as below, by defining a templated function:

```
#include <iostream>

class KeyEvent
{
public: enum TypeFlags {KEYFLAG1=1, KEYFLAG2=2, KEYFLAG3=4};
};

class MouseButtonEvent
{
public: enum TypeFlags {MOUSEFLAG1=1, MOUSEFLAG2=2, MOUSEFLAG3=4};
};

template<typename EC> EC operator|(EC a, EC b)
{
    return static_cast<EC>(static_cast<int>(a)|static_cast<int>(b));
}

void DoSomething(KeyEvent::TypeFlags t) {std::cout << t << std::endl;}

int main()
{
    DoSomething(KeyEvent::KEYFLAG1 | KeyEvent::KEYFLAG2);
    return 0;
}
```

The code above works, but this templated `operator|` is not ideal because it operates on anything. I would like to restrict it to operating on only the Class::TypeFlags enums. I have tried replacing the template above with:

```
template<typename EC> typename EC::TypeFlags operator|(typename EC::TypeFlags a, typename EC::TypeFlags b)
{
    return static_cast<typename EC::TypeFlags>(static_cast<int>(a)|static_cast<int>(b));
}
```

but, while this compiles, the new templated `operator|` is not called [T.C. in the comments has explained why]. (Instead, when the two flags are ORed together, they are implicitly converted to `int`, and the `int` version of `operator|` is called. The resulting `int` then cannot be passed to `DoSomething`.)

Is there a way of writing a templated `operator|` so that it acts on only my `TypeFlags` enums? If it exists, I'd like a solution which a) doesn't allow mixing of flags between different classes, and b) doesn't need to be modified if I add or remove an Event class with flags in it.

Comment: would listing `KeyEvent::TypeFlags` and `MouseButtonEvent::TypeFlags` be enough, or any `SOME_CLASS::TypeFlags` should be matched ?

Comment: @Piotr S. ideally any SOME_CLASS::TypeFlags should be matched. In response to your deleted answer I clarified the question to say that there are rather more than two xxxEvent classes in real codebase.

Comment: Anything to the left of `::` is a non-deduced context. The compiler can't deduce `EC` in your templated operator.

Comment: There are quite some related questions on SO, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/18803940